# SSO between application running on Glassfish 4.1 and one running on Oracle Application Server 10g

Tags: authentication, ldap, oracle-adf, oid, glassfish-4.1

I have to implements a single sign on procedure between 2 web applications.

One of them is running on OAS version 10.1.2, developed using JDeveloper 10g, the application uses ADF framework (10.1.2) and Java 1.4. It authenticates users using a JAZN.xml file, so the users/ passwords aren't in database.

The other is a RESTful application running on a Glassfish 4.1 server, developped in Java 8. Each modules are bundled as OSGi bundles. Authentication not implemented yet.

We were planning on using an LDAP server (Oracle Internet Directory, the only one working with ADF 10.1.2) but I can't seem to be able to find clear documentation about it.

I've found http://java2go.blogspot.com/2012/05/oracle-adf-with-sso-definitive-guide.html which is for WebLogic not OAS, and http://sqltech.cl/doc/oas10gR31/web.1013/b28967/adding_security001.htm which is for version 10.1.3

1- Is there a place with more documentation, how-to, on LDAP configuration with ADF 10.1.2?

2- Is it possible to manage Users/password from the app using LDAP authentication or we must connect to LDAP server to change/create users/passwords?

3- what do you think would be a better approach to implement  SSO?